# Automatic menu creation for pages with categories?

Tags: categories, menus, sidebar

This may be a stretch, but I have a site that has a large number of pages, and i've given the pages categories (with a plugin that let me add categories to pages).
I now want to create a sidebar menu that pulls all the pages from the category of the page you're on.

So if you're on a page that is categorized under 'Beaches', i want it to list all other pages under that category.

If that makes sense.

How can I do that?

Comment: In order to get an actual answer you would have to share **how** pages are categorized. Do they get a post meta? Something else?

Comment: Sorry, the pages were given a new taxonomy titled Categories, which is created within the 'pages' post-type.

Answer (score 0):

The following plugin or his modification might be the solution for you.
Automatically adds menu items by category.
However, the first item must be added manually, and then you must click to automatically add subcategories in the menu item.
If I know correctly, it only adds categories.
No blog posts or pages.

Plugin:

- Add Descendants As Submenu Items
  https://wordpress.org/plugins/add-descendants-as-submenu-items/